# Strange symbols from simple program

Tags: c++, cout

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
string cow=cow;
cout<<cow<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

strangely, the program compiles and runs fine, but the cmd shows strange symbols instead of the word cow.  The symbols are like this ":æ∟ƒí♂"

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you always put quotes around your string. This is how the compiler knows you're referring to a string:

```
    string cow = "cow";
```

The reason your program was able to run was because your string and its variable name are the same, so the computer created a string object called cow and then was instructed to assign that cow variable back to itself, accomplishing nothing. Whatever was in the memory location of the cow object when it was created was then printed to the console.

Answer (score 0):

String should be enclosed inside the doubles quotes:

```
string cow = "cow";
```